# JQuery Mobile 1.4.0 - open Multipage template page from Javascript

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im working on a JQuery Mobile App.

im using the Multipage template feature to navigate between content.

i can easily navigate between pages with an "a" tag using the div page ID ref...

```
<a href="#page2" />
```

if i have the following page stricture...

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <!-- content -->

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <!-- content -->

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">

    <!-- content -->

</div>
```

how can i open page 2 using javascript rather than an a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$.mobile.navigate()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/). For example,

```
$.mobile.navigate("#page2");
```